# Stored procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a function which will get the records from the database.

```
public List<Issue> Load_Issues()
{
    SqlDataReader Sdr;
    List<Issue> ObjList = new List<Issue>();
    cmd.CommandText = "Get_All_Issue";

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        con.Open();
        Sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (Sdr.Read())
        {
            // here I pull out records from database..
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return ObjList;
}
```

The function I am using to bind the Gridview is as follows

```
public void Bind_Issues()
{
    gdIssues.DataSource = Bl.Load_Issues()();
    gdIssues.DataBind();
}
```

My stored procedure doesn't take any arguments. While the page loads for the first time it is working fine and binding the records to the gridview.

We have option to edit the records also, so what happening is after updating records I need to again bind the records to gridview. So I am again using my `Load_Issues` function to do it. But this time it is throwing error

> Get_All_Issues  has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Comment: Do you re-use your `cmd` instance for other queries?

Comment: Need to dispose Sdr btw

Comment: It looks like your `cmd` object exists beyond the scope of the `Load_Issues` function - maybe you use it for the updating logic as well and the parameters are left there from that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most probably re-using the `cmd` instance in multiple places and you don't clear the parameters associated with it, thus creating the exception you're seeing.

Easiest fix would be to not re-use `cmd`, but if for whatever reason it's better for you, just make sure you use Clear on parameters before you execute it.

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: so is it mandatory to clear paramters in each time finally block??

Comment: @user3452210, if you re-use the instance, yes, it's safest this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try not using *global* connections, commands etc: open and close them *within* the method

```
public List<Issue> Load_Issues() {
  //TODO: Put actual connection string here
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String here")) {
    con.Open();

    // Put IDisposable into using
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandText = "Get_All_Issue";
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      List<Issue> ObjList = new List<Issue>();

      // Put IDisposable into using 
      using (var Sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (Sdr.Read()) {
          //TODO: Pull out records from database into ObjList
        }
      } 

      return ObjList; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `using`, so important when dealing with disposable objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try these

```
exec 'stored_procedure_name'
go
```

**or**

```
alter proc stored_procedure_name
as
begin
    --Block of Statements
end
go
```

**or**

```
create proc stored_procedure_name
as
begin
    --Block of Statements
end
go
```

Where **go** keyword will solved your problem.